ILogger Properties BeginScope
What is the proper way to add properties to ILogger using  BeginScope method in following scenario ?
Class Client below needs to add client.Name as property to the every single log. As a example class has only one method client.ByuProduct("product1"), but it would need to be used in any other method.
public class Client
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    public string Name { get; set; }
 
    private Dictionary<string, object> loggedProperties = new();
 
    public Client(ILogger logger, string name)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        Name = name;
        // This is wrong unless the separate instances of logger is created or each Client instance
        // loggerScope = logger.BeginPropertyScope(("customerName", Name));
        loggedProperties.Add("ClientName", name);
    }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Simulating that product was bought by the client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="productId"></param>
    public void BuyProduct(string productId)
    {
        this.logger.LogInformationWithProps(loggedProperties, "Buying product:{ProductId}", productId);
    }
}

I have created extension method LogInformationWithProps and it works OK.
/// <summary>
/// Logs message with properties/structured logging
/// </summary>
/// <param name="logger"></param>
/// <param name="message"></param>
/// <param name="args"></param>
/// <param name="state">The identifier for the scope.</param>
/// <typeparam name="TState">The type of the state to begin scope for.</typeparam>
public static void LogInformationWithProps<TState>(this ILogger logger, TState state, string? message, params object?[] args)
{
 
    using (var scope = logger.BeginScope(state))
    {
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, message, args);
    }
}

I am wondering about performance and best practice. I will have maximum 1-9 instances of the class Client. Should I consider create each client instance its own logger instance and in the constructor should call BeginScope wit clint.Name? I assume that creating logger per Client instance is not best practice.

I guess you make an extension method internal static IDisposable CreateLoggingScope( this ILogger logger, Client client) => logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>(){ [ClientName] = client.Name}); or something alike.
